# "System not initialized. Programmer forgot to call G_gisinit()." message when loading table into GRASS via QGis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to load a CSV table into Grass with `v.in.ascii`from the interface of Qgis 2.0.1 on Windows XP. As the progress bar indicated 74% of the data already loaded, I got the message `"System not initialized. Programmer forgot to call G_gisinit()."`. From that moment on, the loading stops. There is no further error message, the progress bar just gets stuck at 74%.

The exact command was:
`v.in.ascii input=N:/my_path_here/AREA_NOAS04_17_131004.csv output=t7j format=point "fs=;" skip=1 x=1 y=2 z=9 cat=0`

I also tried loading the CSV table into QGis, then importing the resulting vector layer (points) into GRASS with `v.in.ogr.qgis`, with the exact same problem (same message, loading stops at 74%).

If that helps, I'm using the CSV file contained in the Zip archive at the bottom of [this page](http://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/portal/de/index/dienstleistungen/geostat/datenbeschreibung/arealstatistik_noas04.html).

I'm able to load other vector layers from Qgis into GRASS without problems. Might the large size of the dataset (4'128'498 points) be a cause of the problem? I tried to google the error message, but without any helpful results.

Does anyone know what this message means and how I can solve this problem? Thanks a lot!